# React pass data from same child to parent component multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi I would like to pass data from same child to parent component multiple times.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stateVariabes:null
    };
    // callback from parent
    this.props.onSelect(this.state);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const value =  event.target.value;
    this.setState(
      {
        stateVariabes: value
      },
      function() {
        console.log(this.state);
        // callback from parent
        this.props.onSelect(this.state);
      }
    );
  }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      childOne: null,
      childList: [],
      childOther: null

    };
  }
  childCallbackFunction = childData => {
     // which child state shall I set here 
    this.setState({ weekDay: childData });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ChildComponent onSelect={this.childCallbackFunction} />
        <ChildComponent onSelect={this.childCallbackFunction} />
        <ChildComponent onSelect={this.childCallbackFunction} />
        <ChildComponent onSelect={this.childCallbackFunction} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I use only of one the ***ChildComponent*** the update of state from child to parent works as expected but when I have ***multiple ChildComponent*** inside render of Parent the state update does not happen.

Can someone suggest whats the right way to achieve the task?

Comment: If i understood well, you want to share the parent state amongst the children, alrigth? If so, you can use render props or child as function pattern. Or, create a context. Let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Hi, can you make a reproducible example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mL6pzt90/1)? Hard to tell what is wrong -- your ChildComponents never call `handleChange` in your current snippet

Comment: Could you try to swith your parent to PureComponent and see if it works? `class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent`

Comment: Defining separate childCallbackFunction for childOne, childList and childOther helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When using Class components, you need to bind your methods. From React documentation:

> In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, `this` will be undefined when the function is actually called.

So, in your case, your `ChildComponent` should have a

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

You should also remove this from your constructor, since it is calling your callback on initialization:

```
// callback from parent
this.props.onSelect(this.state);
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-night-xlhzj

More information in [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should do it.

child=>

```
class ChildCom extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stateVariabes: null
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {

this.onSelect()
}




  onSelect = () => {
    const value = 'some value coming from your event';
    this.props.trigger(value);
  };
```

Parent=>

```
class ParentCom extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      childOne: null,
      childList: [],
      childOther: null,

    };
  }

  childCallbackFunction = childData => {
    // you can do anything with your child component values here
   console.log('child value: ', childData)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <ChildCom trigger={this.childCallbackFunction} />
        <ChildCom trigger={this.childCallbackFunction} />
        <ChildCom trigger={this.childCallbackFunction} />
        <ChildCom trigger={this.childCallbackFunction} />
      </div>
```